# Uploading php files in GAE

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine

I have some php that I run on my website and I use GAE to host the website. In the app.yaml I have the following:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /my_php/(.*\.php)
  upload: my_php/(.*\.php)
```

The appcfg.py throws `Error parsing hafelha/app.yaml: Unknown url handler type.`
I am wondering if this is due to the fact that I am using python for runtime and uploading php scripts.

Answer (score 0):

"upload" is only for static files. Everything in your app folder will be uploaded by default. Change your handlers section in app.yaml to

```
handlers:
- url: /my_php/(.*\.php)
  script: my_php/\1
```

See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig#PHP_app_yaml_Script_handlers for more details.

Comment: I am using python as the runtime and not php. Using `script: my_php/\1` would throw an error about a potentail threadsafe error. `google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventError: threadsafe cannot be enabled with CGI handler: my_php/\1`

Comment: I see. Any particular reason why you're using python27 runtime instead of php?

Comment: No particular reason, might be a poor choice! I was inspired and started developing from another project I had with python.

Comment: Your runtime setting in app.yaml must match the runtime you wish to use, which is either php or php55 in this case.